# Jquery check all checkboxes doesn't work inside if statement

Tags: jquery, checkbox

The following on page load successfully checks all checkboxes:

```
(function($){

$(':checkbox').prop("checked",true);


}(jQuery));
```

But when running it inside a click event of a button it doesn't, the html value and alert successfully work though so the if statement does work.

```
$('#selectAll').click(function(){
                 if($(this).html() == 'Check All'){
                     $(':checkbox').prop("checked",true);
                     $(this).html('Uncheck All');
                     alert('check all');
                 }
                 else{
                     $(':checkbox').prop("checked",false);
                     $(this).html('Check All');
                     alert('uncheck all');
                 }
            });
```

The below edit shows the html as requested. I believe something is interfering with it as originally said the line to check the checkbox works outside of the if statement. The if statement works and changes the html value of the button. The check the checkbox line does not work inside the if statement though. I was using Datatables.js but have disabled it on this table in case that was having an affect.
EDIT (HTML):

```
<form method="POST" action="http://dev.co.uk/dashboard/export" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" class="form-horizontal"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="fY87JvJYUjeHySDA9kmE72v2I9INRom1X63JyrKr">
<button type="button" class="btn green" id="selectAll">Check All</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn blue">Export</button>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="export">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Select</th>
<th>Sku</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Belongs to</th>
<th>Brand</th>
<th>Category(s)</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr>
<td> <label><input class="form-control selectAll" name="products[]" type="checkbox" value="1">  </label> </td>
<td> Product1 </td>
<td> Red T-shirt </td>
<td> T-Shirts </td>
<td> EZ T </td>
<td> Clothing, </td>
<td> Blurb goes here </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> <label><input class="form-control selectAll" name="products[]" type="checkbox" value="2">  </label> </td>
<td> Product2 </td>
<td> blue T-shirt </td>
<td> T-Shirts </td>
<td> EZ T </td>
<td> Clothing, </td>
<td> Blurb goes here </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> <label><input class="form-control selectAll" name="products[]" type="checkbox" value="3">  </label> </td>
<td> Product3 </td>
<td> green T-shirt </td>
<td> T-Shirts </td>
<td> EZ T </td>
<td> Clothing, </td>
<td> Blurb goes here </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> <label><input class="form-control selectAll" name="products[]" type="checkbox" value="4">  </label> </td>
<td> Product4 </td>
<td> Purple T-shirt </td>
<td> T-Shirts </td>
<td> EZ T </td>
<td> Clothing, </td>
<td> Blurb goes here </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: works fine check it https://jsfiddle.net/sanchitpatiyal95/krncqumr/

Comment: Can you add the html too? Maybe you mistyped something.

Comment: @TudorLeustean if i mistyped something why would it work outside of the if statement?

Comment: The first code snipplet doesn't have the click handler, or the if else logic.  That's the logic that may have a typo in it.

Answer (score 0):

I could do with seeing your html but should the if statement not be `if($(this).val() == 'Check All'){`

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement seems to be working fine. I had trouble trying to get your first function working though. I've made a few adjustments and added comments in the code. Basically I used `$(document).ready` to fire some code and then `$(#selectAll).click` for your click events. Hope it helps!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':checkbox').prop("checked",false); // run this on load
  $('#selectAll').html('Check All'); // run this on load
  $('#selectAll').click(function(){  // run everything here when an item is clicked
     if($(this).html() == 'Check All'){
         $(':checkbox').prop("checked",true);
         $(this).html('Uncheck All');
     }
     else{
         $(':checkbox').prop("checked",false);
         $(this).html('Check All');
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addClass`, `removeClass` & `hasClass` to check/uncheck all checkboxes. It's recommended to use class and not check for strings/text in `if` condition:

```js
$('#selectAll').click(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(':checkbox').prop("checked", true);
    $(this).html('Uncheck All').addClass('active');
    alert('check all');
  } else {
    $(':checkbox').prop("checked", false);
    $(this).html('Check All').removeClass('active');
    alert('uncheck all');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="http://dev.co.uk/dashboard/export" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" class="form-horizontal"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="fY87JvJYUjeHySDA9kmE72v2I9INRom1X63JyrKr">
  <button type="button" class="btn green" id="selectAll">Check All</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn blue">Export</button>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="export">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>Sku</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Belongs to</th>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Category(s)</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td> <label><input class="form-control selectAll" name="products[]" type="checkbox" value="1">  </label> </td>
        <td> Product1 </td>
        <td> Red T-shirt </td>
        <td> T-Shirts </td>
        <td> EZ T </td>
        <td> Clothing, </td>
        <td> Blurb goes here </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td> <label><input class="form-control selectAll" name="products[]" type="checkbox" value="2">  </label> </td>
        <td> Product2 </td>
        <td> blue T-shirt </td>
        <td> T-Shirts </td>
        <td> EZ T </td>
        <td> Clothing, </td>
        <td> Blurb goes here </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td> <label><input class="form-control selectAll" name="products[]" type="checkbox" value="3">  </label> </td>
        <td> Product3 </td>
        <td> green T-shirt </td>
        <td> T-Shirts </td>
        <td> EZ T </td>
        <td> Clothing, </td>
        <td> Blurb goes here </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td> <label><input class="form-control selectAll" name="products[]" type="checkbox" value="4">  </label> </td>
        <td> Product4 </td>
        <td> Purple T-shirt </td>
        <td> T-Shirts </td>
        <td> EZ T </td>
        <td> Clothing, </td>
        <td> Blurb goes here </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips, this has the same effect as my original post though. Something must be interfering with it when inside of the click event.